# AMD FirePro S7150 Cloud Gaming

Tags: cloud, xendesktop

just a fun question today.
I´m thinking about using a FirePro S7150 with Citrix XenDesktop to enable me and my friends to play games on older notebooks over the internet. Has anyone experience with that? Do you think FirePro S7150 would be powerfull enough to play games like Overwatch, Fortnite or CS:GO?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to run most games, including Overwatch on high settings. 
This link shows the details: https://www.amd.com/Documents/FirePro-S-Series-Datasheet.pdf

I do not have one myself, but through research I found that you should be fine.